# Show a continous function is bounded on a closed interval

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, continuity

For a homework problem, I need to show a function $\pi + 0.5\sin(\frac{x}{2})$ is bounded on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I'm having trouble conceptualizing a good way to do this though. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: You know that $-1\leq\sin\theta\leq1$, for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, then it's just multiply this inequality by $0.5$ and sum $\pi$, what do you obtain?

Comment: @DiegoMath $-0.5 + \pi \le \pi + 0.5\sin(\theta) \le 0.5 + \pi$. But does this still hold when $\theta = \frac{x}{2}$?

Comment: @DiegoMath post your answer below so I can give you credit.

Comment: The answer was posted below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that 
$$−1≤\sin\theta≤1, \forall θ∈[0,2π],$$
Then it's just multiply this inequality by 0.5 and sum π, thus
$$-0.5+\pi\leq\pi+0.5\sin\theta\leq0.5+\pi.$$

Therefore your expression is bounded!

Answer (score 0):

$1\geq \sin(x) \geq -1$ for all values of $x \in \mathbb R$.

So, $\pi+0.5 \geq \pi+0.5\sin(\frac{x}{2}) \geq \pi -0.5$

These are your bounds.

If it is bounded on all $\mathbb R$, then it is bounded for a subset of $\mathbb R$, namely, $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this function is bounded since $|\sin(x)|\le 1$ for all reals $x$.